# Converting static CASE WHEN statements to dynamic to supply to .annotate()

Tags: python, django

I have this ORM query that is working well. I tested the following to see the output and it is as expected actually:

```
members=Members.objects.all().annotate(age_groups=Case(
                When(birthdate__year__range=(2007,2017), then=Value('0-10')),
                When(birthdate__year__range=(1997,2006), then=Value('11-20')),
                When(birthdate__year__range=(1987,1996), then=Value('21-30')),
                When(birthdate__year__range=(1977,1986), then=Value('31-40')),
                When(birthdate__year__range=(1967,1976), then=Value('41-50')),
                When(birthdate__year__range=(1957,1966), then=Value('51-60')),
                When(birthdate__year__range=(1947,1956), then=Value('61-70')),
                When(birthdate__year__range=(1937,1946), then=Value('71-80')),
                When(birthdate__year__range=(1927,1936), then=Value('81-90')),
                When(birthdate__year__range=(1917,1926), then=Value('91-100')),
                default=Value('100+'),  output_field=CharField())
                ).values('age_groups',).annotate(total=Count('age_groups'))
```

But I want to move it to a function so users can specify the date field they want to work with and do grouping they prefer(e.g 0-20, 21-40 etc). For that, I wrote the following function which simply outputs the `CASE WHEN statements` as a string when called. The problem is when I pass it to `annotate()` I get the `str` has `no resolve error`.

Hope you get what I want to do. I need to pass the output of the following function to `annoate()`:

```
from datetime import date
def AgeGrouping(field_name,required_min_age=0,required_max_age=100,jump_by=10):
now_year=date.today().year

reply='Case('
just_started=True
for i in range(now_year-required_min_age,now_year-required_max_age,-jump_by):

    if just_started==False:
        min_age=max_age + 1
        max_age=min_age + 9

    else:
        min_age= now_year - i
        max_age= min_age + 10

    min_year=now_year- min_age
    max_year= now_year - max_age

    reply="\n".join([reply,"When(" + field_name + "__year__range=(" + str(max_year) + "," + str(min_year) + "), then=Value('" + str(min_age) + "-" + str(max_age) + "')),"])

    just_started=False

reply="\n".join([reply, "default=Value('100+'),  output_field=models.CharField())"])

return reply
```

Then call it like this:

```
   print(AgeGrouping('birthdate',required_min_age=0,required_max_age=100,jump_by=10))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach is to create a string that contains the code required. It is possible to evaluate the string as code, but this can have security issues.

A better approach would be to create a list of `When()` objects using the loop. Then you can unpack the list when you call `Case()` in your annotation.

```
def age_grouping(field_name, required_min_age=0, required_max_age=100, jump_by=10):
    ...
    whens = []
    for i in range(now_year-required_min_age,now_year-required_max_age,-jump_by):
       # Set min_age, max_age, min_year, max_year
       ...
       description = '%s-%s' % (min_age, max_age)  # e.g. '0-10'
       # create dict of kwargs for When()
       kwargs = {'%s__year__range' % field_name: (min_year, max_year)}
       whens.append(When(then=Value(description), **kwargs))

    # Return the Case() object that you can pass to annotate()
    return Case(*whens, default=Value('100+'), output_field=CharField())
```

You should then be able to call

```
Members.objects.all().annotate(age_groups=age_grouping(...))
```